# Opening a folder locating a specific file in Ubuntu Nautilus Browser

Tags: c, ubuntu, nautilus

My requirement is simple, I hope some intelligent geeks can help me here out.

I am working on a project[LINUX-UBUNTU], I have a **c program**, in which I have a char array having a path to a file, an want to open that folder in Ubuntu nautilus browser, also I want that file to get selected automatically possible.

Any help or guidance will be great.

--

Thanks

Alok Kr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *popen* (or any from its family) to call nautilus.  On one hand, if the argument is a directory, then nautilus will open a window with that directory.  On the other hand, if the argument is a file, then nautilus will open a window in that directory with that file selected.